# In a Git or other VCS, Is there a keyboard shortcut way to jump to the modified lines of code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

In Atom and IntelliJ there is the feature that you can set to keyboard shortcuts (In Atom it's default ⌥G+Up/Down), and that jumps from wherever you are in the file and takes you to the modified lines of code if the file is tracked by a VCS. So for example in Atom, if I kept hitting ⌥G+Up, it would continually keep jumping to modified lines that were upwards throughout the file.

I haven't been able to find anything, and this is a very useful feature to me. Is there a keyboard shortcut feature for that in VSCode that I'm missing, or is there a feature request for it already out?

Comment: I don't think my original question and description described exactly what I wanted, so I have edited my description. Hopefully this makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by clicking on the "source control icon" in the activity bar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>

Then right-click a modified file and select "Open changes".

**Set your focus within the opened editor.**

<kbd>F7</kbd> will then take you to your next change. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to the previous change.

If you meant without having to open up a diff editor, I don't think there is any way to jump to changes other than by clicking in the right margin where the color change indicators are.

Comment: Ya, no I would like to just stay within the file without having to jump to anything else. I appreciate the response though

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (**Spilt Editor**) keyboard shortcut to jump to the lines for pervious commit.

It will show two windows for the current file for comparison, you can edit on any side of the file.

[image]